# css inner border transparent not working in my site,

Tags: javascript, html, css

This inner border transparent only works for single page or jsfiddle,
But not working in my website, what's wrong with my code?
Anyone can help plz…

on jsfiddle working good.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MuCY7/1/)

but my site photo does not show `:(`

[image]

Comment: Put the link of your site photo to see differences

Comment: testing server

http://salma-test.site90.net/

Answer (score 0):

I added `z-index` and `position: relative` to `.item` class like this:

```
.item {
   width: 21%;
   float: left;
   display: block;
   margin: 20px 2%;
   padding: 0px;
   cursor: pointer;

   /* Code added */
   position: relative;
   z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: I cannot detect problem in fadeIn effect if you don't correct position of image on you site (testing server)

Comment: also ie8 not load photos.

Comment: Now you talk about another subject (Cross-browser compatibility), box-shadow doesn't work in IE8 : http://caniuse.com/css-boxshadow

Comment: The cause of hidden images on IE8 is `(filter: alpha(opacity=0))` in style attribute of `<img/>`